# How to display random 10 record from database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, random

How to randomly display 10 question from database? How can i check the answer is correct with database or not?

```
        db.command(true, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE Age_group='" +category + "'");
        foreach (DataRow item in db.result.Rows)
        {
            question_list.Add (Convert.ToInt32(item["id"]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < max_question; i++)
        {
            int index = ran.Next(question_list.Count);
            question_choose.Add(question_list[index]);
            question_list.Remove(question_list[index]);
        }
```

Comment: Order by rand() and take 10.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848872/select-n-random-rows-from-sql-server-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 10 * from table order by newid()
```

also, see ["order by newid()" - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979799/order-by-newid-how-does-it-work)

Comment: ya, it's work. How can i random 10 question belong to the age category that i choose?

Comment: you can try select top 10 * from table where age>10 order by newid()

Comment: that's not work, i got try SELECT top 15 * FROM question where age_group='" +category+ "order by newid()" but still not work too

Comment: in your example, you have one extra single quote before category -> age_group =  ' " +category....

Comment: ya, In the form, i will put 3 type of category which is 6-10, 11-15, 16-20 to let the user choose, at the last how can i know the age category choose by user and random the question to them?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. If you ask how to get questions from an age interval, it'll be: Where age>6 AND age<10. If you mean, how to know what user has been chose, you can make a radio button menu which returns 1 if he selected 6-10, returns 2 if selected 11-15 and so on. Than, comparing this number, you select what condition to add in the query: if(radioBtn==1) { querry +=" Where age>6 AND age<10";} else querry+= "Where age>10 AND age<16";