# In Sql Result not to get repeated Id's or result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Assume that i have a table below

```
S.no   Question
 1      XXX 
 2      XXX
 3      XXX 
 4      XXX
 5      XXX
 6      XXX
 7      XXX
 8      XXX
 9      XXX
 10     XXX
```

and i want to get a random new result from the table and i dont want repeated id's and i have tried

```
SET @Q_ID=(SELECT Top 1 S.No from Table  order by NEWID())
```

but im getting sometimes repeated results , can anyone help me???

Comment: Is it a requirement to return **one** random row at a time? There are simple ways to return a unique result set.

Comment: yes every time i execute the query i want to get newer id's

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I assume SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity'; is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store your already returned result somewhere (for eaxample in another table) and then add a LEFT JOIN to check the value does not exist.

Here's the table

```
CREATE table AlreadyReturned
(
  Id int,
  UserName varchar(200)
)
```

And here's the code:

```
DECLARE @Q_ID int

// @Username will be passed as a paremeter of course, here
// it is set for simplicity
DECLARE @Username varchar(200)
SET @Username = 'test' 

WHILE @Q_ID IS NULL
 BEGIN
    SET @Q_ID=(
          SELECT Top 1 MyTable.[No] 
          FROM MyTable LEFT OUTER JOIN AlreadyReturned 
              ON MyTable.[No] = AlreadyReturned.Id AND AlreadyReturned.UserName = @UserName 
          WHERE AlreadyReturned.Id IS NULL order by NEWID())

    IF @Q_ID IS NULL
       DELETE FROM AlreadyReturned WHERE UserName = @Username
END 

INSERT INTO AlreadyReturned VALUES (@Q_ID, @Username)

SELECT @Q_ID
```

Take care this code is like a "Time Bomb", as it works until the AlreadyReturned table does not contain all the values that are present in the MyTable table

Comment: yeah you are right but where i want to clear the AlreadyReturned tables for new users who are attending the questions

Comment: Ok, you have to add a UserId field to the table, I'll update the answer

Comment: the user will attend questions as many times he want, is it right to store his username every time he attends???

Comment: Yes, it's the only way to check whether he already obtained that value in the past.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions and im gona try it :) and also i think i have to write a trigger to clear the table once in a month or week

Comment: Maybe you can clear it when you don't have any new result, would you like to have the code for this too :-)

Comment: @dazzlingkumar Obviously it would be better to store the user **Id**, but we don't know your db design. If you have user id's, use them instead

Comment: yeah it would be better to have it  @PaoloCosta :)

Comment: I delete the comment with the email

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store whatever random question id was selected and exclude from selecting next time . Create a table `QuestionsSelectedTable` which stores already selected questions.

```
SET @Q_ID=(SELECT Top 1 S.No from Table  WHERE [S.No] NOT IN (SELECT Qid FROM QuestionsSelectedTable ) order by NEWID())
INSERT INTO QuestionsSelectedTable(Qid) VALUES(@QID)
```

Doing  `ORDER BY NEWID()` selects randomly but is not guaranteed to return different result everytime as there is no dependency to the result which was generated before. Smaller the no of records in table , more are the chances of repeated results.

See here how [**NEWID()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979799/order-by-newid-how-does-it-work) works

Comment: yes ur's also similar to Paolo Costa but where i want to clear the AlreadyReturned tables for new users who are attending the questions