# Is there a simple way to pick random records (about 20) from a data table with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Here is the code I used

```
SELECT * FROM   
(SELECT * FROM [table name] 
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum < 10
```

I would like to select random rows only from records with column A = XYZ. I tried to add a WHERE clause in the code:

```
SELECT * FROM   
(SELECT * FROM [table name] 
WHERE [column A] = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum < 10
```

but got an error. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: are you able to run a simple query that returns all `A = XYZ` records?

Comment: it doesn't look too odd. but without the error text, we're just guessing. My guess is that the current user is not allowed to access dbms_random.value.

Comment: Your first query would not work in SQL Server.  Tag the question with the database that you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below approach in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [table name] 
WHERE [column A] = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY newid()
```

[More information on how ORDER BY newid() works in a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979799/order-by-newid-how-does-it-work)

Comment: also could be very inefficient. question has been asked several times before

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Oracle code.  It does not recognize square braces for identifiers.  In fact, don't escape them -- or use double quotes if you must:

```
SELECT t.*   
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM t 
      WHERE columnA = 'XYZ'
      ORDER BY dbms_random.value
     ) t
WHERE rownum < 10;
```

In SQL Server, the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT TOP (10) t.*
FROM t 
WHERE columnA = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . The OP claims that s/he used the first query, presumably with no error.  That strongly suggests that the OP is not using SQL Server.